# How to develop the scrolling functionality using buttons

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i am using UIScroll view.That will be scrolled vertically when i perform the touch operations on that scroll view.But i need to perform that top scroll and bottom scroll operations using top and bottom buttons.So please tell me how to perform this scrolling operation using that buttons.

Comment: Why would you change the way that Apple define ? it'll confuse user

Comment: User don't know scrolling is there or not if we didn't place the buttons.

Comment: if it's a UIScrollView he will know it no ? it's a basic IOS interaction

Comment: With out scrollview how to perform the scrolling operations using buttons.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, this is not really recommended. However, it is possible...

For the "Top" button, use this code:
`[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20) animated:YES];`

Use a similar approach for the "Bottom" button, taking into account the height of your scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting Buttons and adding scrolling functionality on those button, Just flash right / left indicator images using animation to user,so that user can come to know there is more content than current page.

Comment: No need to scroll right and left.I need to scroll top and bottom.

Comment: he say you should flash the scroll bar, so the user will se it easily